# How to merge multiple objective-c frameworks?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there an easy way to merge multiple objective-c frameworks into one master framework?

Comment: Hm interesting question.  Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import the frameworks into a single framework. That's what Cocoa does, after all: UIKit is a vast list of `import` statements importing other frameworks.